# Security requirements for opened port?

Tags: internet, port-security

I am a programmer and wanted to open a port for example 34000 on my public server, that my customer could use it.

What kind of security concerns that I would face?

Comment: What information is on the server ?  How do you authenticate ? Is it a web service ? What else is on the inside of your server/network ?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else in the world can also access the port, poke around at it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, only "hardened" services should ever be exposed to the Internet - the service behind the port needs to be proofed against all kinds of attacks. Making an unsecure application accessible to the Internet, there's no question *if* you're hacked, only *when*.

However, limiting access to the port/service (by firewall rules or ACLs) can greatly reduce the security problem. So, if you can e.g. restrict the networks/IP ranges that can contact the service the risks may be tolerable.

You can also use a VPN-only logic to restrict access to a known group of users, regardless of where they are.

All these are security considerations and weighting the project manager has to do in accordance to the customer's requirements.